# What's the short circuiting way to rewrite for loop that breaks when condition is met?

Tags: javascript

Is there a shorter way (probably using short circuiting) to write the if part of the for-loop?

```
let range = new Array()
for (let i = 0; i < buckets.length; i++) {  //bucket is an array of sets. 
  if (buckets[i].size > 0) {
    range[0] = i;  //set index of the first none-empty element in buckets to be range[0]
    break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are searching for [`findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)

```
let range = []

range.push(buckets.findIndex(bucket => bucket.size > 0))
```